# аудит безопасности WI-FI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

Я хочу провести аудит безопасности(взломать) точек WI-FI.
Использую *Linux Ubuntu* версии *20.10*.

Comment: так взломать или аудит безопасности?

Comment: получить пароль.

Comment: мой вопрос не поменялся. Если делать аудит, то просто открываете настройки роутера и смотрите. Готово.

Answer (score 1):

Вот неплохие [вводная стать 1](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/534112/) и [вводная статья 2](https://habr.com/ru/company/xakep/blog/143834/), которая объясняет, как происходит "взлом WiFi и получение пароля"

Если в двух словах, то Ваша задача сводится вот к чему: есть эфир. Радиоэфир. По нему летают пакеты клиентов, уже подключившихся к WiFi точке доступа и "работающих" через неё.

Вы можете делать что угодно - перехватывать пакеты, "излучать" свои пакеты, прикидываться точкой доступа с тем же именем, брать клиентов в заложники... хотя последнее, наверное, немного чересчур.

Ваша задача - по доступной из перехваченного трафика информации восстановить пароль.

Если отбросить совсем уж "слабые" случаи, вроде использования WEP, то вам придётся, скорее всего, бороться с WPA-2 Personal, использующих в качестве алгоритмов шифрования AES или TKIP или и то и другое.

В этом смысле самый лакомый кусочек - это перехват начала WiFi сесии, как раз когда клиент WiFi авторизуется.

В этом случае Вы перехватываете некий хеш его пароля. Потом можно или воспользоваться радужными таблицами, или запустить перебор на GPU, или просто "угадать" (побобрать методом перебора) пароль.

При этом не рассматривается ситуация, когда используется WPA2-Enterprise. В этой балалайке происходит то, что называется "авторизацией по ключам", и это равносильно тому, что пароль начинает иметь очень большую длинну (длинну ключа). Как правило, ключ для такого сценария "прописывают" в корпоративный ноут, копируя его с флешки, и он там остаётся на всё время использования. Если я всё правильно понимаю - такая схема не подвержена атакам через перехват пакетов - для реально длинных ключей никаких радужных таблиц не хватит.

Comment: мне нужно получить пароль от чужой точки Wi-Fi.

Comment: Пробуйте проделать процедуру по приведенным статьям...

Comment: я попробовал провести процедуру со статейками.
не работает. не отображаются сведения.

Comment: А на каком шаге из статьи 1 перестаёт получаться?

Comment: статья 1, шаг 5

Comment: Хм, ничего не могу сказать... Проблема может быть либо в том, что адаптер не переключается в режим захвата всего трафика, либо еще в чем то. В любом случае - вы уже знаете, в каком направлении копать :-)

Comment: а есть вариант ещё, кроме aircrack-ng?

Comment: Боюсь, я здесь уже ничего не могу подсказать. Попробуйте поискать статьи по тем же ключевым словам, что и в приведенных двух.